# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, timestamp

I have the following error with my app trying to insert data in a MariaDB 10.3 database.

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value:
'2023-03-26 02:51:42' for column `db`.`table`.`column` at row 1
(SQL: insert into `column` (`clicked_at`) values (2023-03-26 02:51:42)
```

The column is a timestamp column.
MariaDB states :

> Timestamps in MariaDB have a maximum value of 2147483647, equivalent
> to 2038-01-19 05:14:07. This is due to the underlying 32-bit
> limitation.

My value '2023-03-26 02:51:42' is in UTC and less than '2038-01-19 05:14:07'.

This error came out of the blue 13 times despite nothing was changed in my code
and nothing was touched on the database according to my server provider.

What could be the issue here?

Strict mode is not enabled but I don't think it's relevant here.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/a5-dkAn1

Comment: at that date was the time changed to sommer time, so that hour is not valid as the time change from 2 to 3 directly without any time passing

Comment: But UTC has no daylight saving time.

Comment: I sent the value in UTC and also I don't understand why it counts that the date is in "the future" anyways since i'm supposed to be able to add dates uptil 2038-01-19 05:14:07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/timestamp/#time-zones) state:

> If a column uses the TIMESTAMP data type, then any inserted values are
> converted from the session's time zone to Coordinated Universal Time
> (UTC) when stored, and converted back to the session's time zone when
> retrieved.

Because the time doesn't exist in the current session's time zone (daylight saving) the value is not allowed.

Comment: but I sent the date in UTC format so I don't understand why this would happen.

Comment: What do you mean "UTC format"? What timezone did your session/your app have? That's the timezone MariaDB is interpreting the datestring as.

Comment: yes my MariaDB was not in UTC although I created a UTC date with my library, that seemed to be the issue.